# Shapely not detecting Manhattan point in Pluto dataset

Tags: shapely, fiona

I have a shapefile for Manhattan taken from the Pluto dataset:

https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-pluto-mappluto.page

Removing it from the zip, I load it with Fiona.

```
import fiona
import shapely
fiona_shape_pluto_mn = fiona.open("MNMapPLUTO.shp")
first = fiona_shape_pluto_mn.next()
shp_geom = shapely.geometry.shape(first['geometry'])
```

According to the Pluto CSV file for Manhattan (MN2017V11.csv), these points correspond to Bush Tower in Manhattan: 988230, 214299

But when I run the following I get `False`:

`shp_geom.contains(shapely.geometry.Point(988230, 214299))`

Comment: Did you plot the data  because your point is not within  any polygon

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I had thought fiona was loading the entire shapefile. It appears to only be loading a part. When I load it into a multipolygon `mp = MultiPolygon([shape(pol['geometry']) for pol in fiona.open(f_MN)])` and run `mp.contains(Point(987838,195989))`, I get a `TopologicalError`.

Comment: Whether you use a polygon or a multipolygon, the problem remains the same, none of them contains the point.